# OpenShift: Add SCC to Service Account in Yaml

Tags: openshift

Is there an equivalent for the following command in yaml? Using OpenShift 4.2 currently

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user <scc_name> <user_name>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.2/authentication/managing-security-context-constraints.html#security-context-constraints-example_configuring-internal-oauth)'s example of SCC.
You have to add  element to 'users' list, so you can export the SCC and re-apply modifyed object.